# converting floating point values to ascii and back again without introducing errors

Tags: c++, encoding, floating-point, ascii

At first sight, this seems trivial, but the usual (radix 2 <-> radix 10)  *FP<->ASCII* conversions cannot always be done without introducing errors. Granted, these are small, but what options exist to make the conversions to and from ASCII perfect, that is, what are the possibilities of making the conversions, without introducing any error at all? I was thinking about *base64* encoding, or bit-encoding (e.g. something like `11110101010...`), both of these would preserve the radix.

EDIT: Since I can't answer myself, here's what I had in mind:

```
double d{.1};

auto const s(::std::to_string(*reinterpret_cast<::std::uint64_t*>(&d)));
::std::uint64_t n(::std::stoull(s));

auto const e(*reinterpret_cast<double*>(&n));

assert(d == e);
```

Comment: If you can assume IEEE-754 then you could just use the ASCII hex representation - a 4 byte float would need 8 ASCII characters, and an 8 byte double would require 16.

Comment: "cannot always be done without introducing errors." - that's just nonsense. IEEE-754 floating point numbers are just a sequence of 4 of 8 bytes, which can be encoded however you like without introducing any errors sans the ones that have already been present in the floating representation itself. VTC as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Well, I am right. Try to represent `1e-1` as a floating point number.

Comment: @PaulR I think there are issues with endianess with that approach?

Comment: @user1095108 Floating point numbers cannot represent everything that you can write as a string literal. So once you convert to a floating point number, you did a lossy conversion. However, FP -> string is possible in a perfect way if you simply encode the bytes of the floating point number.

Comment: @user1095108 You have failed to read *and comprehend* what I wrote. The errors related to IEEE-754 representation are **completely irrelevant** to the fact whether you store them as ASCII or binary. In particular `0.1` might be seen as a `Rational` type, not as a `Floating` type in some languages.

Comment: @user1095108 _'I think there are issues with endianess'_ You can easily overcome these by normalizing (use hton<x>,ntoh<x>).

Comment: @isarandi That's true, but I seem to recall things, such as the floating-point hidden bit, used for rounding. How can I get at that bit?

Comment: @user1095108: You don't need to care. Just take the `sizeof` for your floating point argument and take all bytes that are stored inside. Then you have a perfect byte for byte representation of the floating point number. No matter how they actually implement it.

Comment: folks, how about casting the fp to an integral type and then converting the integer to ascii? That would seem architecture independent?

Comment: @user1095108 you have just introduced an additional step that doesn't buy you anything whatsover, because *floating point numbers already have a defined binary representation*. As for endianness, it's an orthogonal problem.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, and it spans several bytes, therefore endianess considerations are valid, I think.

Comment: @user1095108 Which brings us to "how to serialize bytes over systems with different endianness", which in turn would be an nth duplicate on SO.

Comment: @user1095108: You shouldn't really care about this. Convert to a string with enough decimal places (maybe a hundred if you want such accuracy) after the comma (in scientific notation). Or if you want to store it, store the floats in binary form (binary file, not ascii).

Comment: @isarandi I recall a game, called `ufo2000`, that sometimes went "out of sync", precisely because the authors did not serialize floats perfectly, sometimes you simply can't afford hundreds of decimal places (i.e. in games, with floats sent over the network). Many people underestimate the intricacies of floats.

Comment: @user1095108 ufo2000 went out of sync because they expected floating point computations to be *exactly* the same on different platforms ([source](http://ufo2000.sourceforge.net/news.php)). It was not related to serialization at all; it's just how floating-point numbers work.

Comment: @user1095108 Re the hidden bit, there's no way you can get at that, because it is not stored in memory.  It is only present in the FPU after an operation, to ensure correct rounding of the results of the operation.

Comment: @isarandi Just dumping the bytes will _not_ guarantee that you will be able to reread it.  IEEE doesn't place any requirements on the format of the representation, and not only does byte order vary, but I've heard that there are subtle differences in NaNs.

Comment: And since it has been mentioned: there isn't really a way to get a `double` into an `unsigned long long` without introducing undefined behavior somewhere.  (In practice, a `memcpy` is almost guaranteed to work on all machines supporting IEEE, and with most compilers, there are tricks with either `reinterpret_cast` or `union` which will work as well.)

Comment: @James Kanze: Are you saying that IEEE 754 doesn't guarantee the binary representation of the float? It's my understanding that is the whole point of the standard, IEEE 754. Surly, endian issues aside, dumping and reading the bytes of a standard representation will preserve all the state.

Comment: @Apriori IEEE guarantees the representation, but not the format that representation may take.

Comment: Interesting read on the subject:
http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/
In conclusion, 9 digits for floats and 17 digits for doubles are sufficient to ensure round-trip.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean exactly by "without introducing errors"?  If it
is for the machine to reread later, 17 digits precision
guarantees round trip: the actual value in the text will not be
the exact value of the double, but it will be closer to the
original double value than to any other double value, so
reconversion to double will result in the initial value.  If you
have access to C++11, you can also set the format to output the
value in hex:

```
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::fixed | std::ios_base::scientific,
                std::ios_base::floatfield );
```

In this case, the output should be exact, regardless of the
precision.

If it is for humans to read, and know the exact value, there is
nothing in the standard library which will guarantee this.  In
theory, outputting 53 digits should suffice, but the neither the
C++ standard nor the IEEE standard require the implementation to
guard against rounding errors in the conversion routine at this
precision, and some implementations just append a sufficiently
large number of `'0'` after the 19th or 20th digit, rather than
waste runtime calculating incorrect values.

Comment: Naturally, for the machine, as "for humans", automatically means radix 10. Hopefully a reopen will happen.

Comment: While it is true that 17 decimal digits are sufficient to uniquely identify every IEEE-754 double operand (e.g. by using the format `% 23.16e`), and thus allow round-trip conversions, many conversion routines contain flaws that throw a wrench into this. Some such flaws are pointed out by this blog: http://www.exploringbinary.com/. An alternative way of printing floating-point operands directly based on their binary representation exists in C (but I believe not C++; although it may be available as a compiler extension): the `%a` format, e.g. `% 21.12a`.

Comment: @njuffa If 17 decimal digits aren't sufficient for a round trip, it is a very serious error in the library, serious enough to make it unusable for any floating point work.  IEEE specifies very clearly what is needed.  And I pointed out the possibility of a hexadecimal representation in my answer above; it's part of C++11.  (Also, you _shouldn't_ specify the precision when using `"%a"` in C; C++ will ignore it, but in C, it will override the library's own choice, which should be the minimum necessary to ensure an exact representation.)

Comment: @James Kanze: My comment was not meant to express disagreement with your answer, just pointing out that there is residual risk since various commonly used conversion routines, including gcc, until recently, have apparently had flaws (see the blog I pointed to for specific cases). Likewise, my mention of the `%a` format was an attempt to add a bit of additional information to what you stated about hexadecimal output. I was unaware of the precision specifier issue with `%a`, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question you are asking is how to round-trip a floating point double value via an ASCII (string) representation. I agree, for this purpose printing the number in fixed or floating point decimal notation is completely unsuitable.

If you don't care what the string looks like then the simple solution is to just treat the 8 byte double as two integers. Two hex integers will occupy 16 character positions. With practice you can even read one of these and estimate the value.

The same thing in Base-64 just reduces the number of character positions (to 11/12). The number formatted this way is quite unreadable.

There are other ways, but why bother? These should suffice.